# Start application without install apk

Tags: android

I have an application which unsigned. I want to start this application without install it. 
I stored the downloaded application on sdcard and use my main-app to load it.

```
final String apkFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/Download/app-debug.apk";
String className = "com.example.myapplication.MainActivity";
String methodToInvoke = "onCreate";
final File optimizedDexOutputPath = getDir("outdex", 0);

//try to get class
DexClassLoader dLoader = new DexClassLoader(apkFile,optimizedDexOutputPath.getAbsolutePath(),
                null,ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getParent());

try {
      Class<?> loadedClass = dLoader.loadClass(className);
      Object obj = (Object)loadedClass.newInstance();
      Method m = loadedClass.getMethod(methodToInvoke,Bundle.class); //failed here
      m.invoke(obj, savedInstanceState);

 } catch (....) {
    //NoSuchMethodException
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

app-debug.apk

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import *

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toast.makeText(this, "hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

But I always get `NoSuchMethodException`.

Comment: It will not work as loaded classes cannot access resourcs from given apk but rather from apk which is running

Comment: @Selvin so is it possible to start an unsigned app without install in android ?

Comment: No, you can only use classes from classes.dex but context (Aplication/Activity/etc..) will use resources from host apk ... more over Activity is started by system ... so if it's not installed system doesn't know where to search ... so obviously any call of `startActivity` with Activity from not installed will end with exception

Comment: you may use fragments but remeber - you cannot access this apk resources so no layout - you have to build it via code